# Angular Firebase (AngularFire) CRUD SHOW and EDIT pages?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, crud, angularfire

To learn AngularFire I'm trying to build a simple CRUD app. The INDEX and NEW pages went smoothly but I'm stuck on the SHOW and EDIT pages. I can't get a selected record to display on the SHOW page.

With MongoDB and Angular it's easy to make the SHOW page. On the INDEX page you put in an anchor link with the ID of the record you want to show:

```
<a ng-href="#/{{record._id}}"><span>{{record.title}}</span<</a>
```

This puts the record ID into the URL, e.g., `www.website.com/#/K9hr32rhror`

Then on the SHOW page you can use `{{record.title}}` or `{{record.author}}` or whatever you want. Angular magically remembers the ID of the record you clicked on the INDEX page. How Angular does this I have no idea. :-)

In MongoDB the ID is called `_id`. In Firebase the ID is called `$id`. So I changed the code on the INDEX page to

```
<a ng-href="#/{{record.$id}}"><span>{{record.title}}</span<</a>
```

This successfully puts the ID into the URL.

The problem is that no record is displayed on the SHOW page. Angular appears to have forgotten what `{{record}}` refers to.

I tried putting in a leading `/`:

```
<a ng-href="/#/{{record._id}}"><span>{{record.title}}</span<</a>
```

That makes no difference.

I tried parsing the ID from the URL with

```
var key = location.hash.split('#/')[1]
```

This returns the ID. When I console.log the $firebaseArray(ref) object I see a collection (array) of all my records. But when I use `collection.$getRecord(key)` or `collection.$keyAt(0)` or `collection.$indexFor(key)` I get null or -1, indicating that AngularFire can't find the record.

Here's my full controller code:

```
app.controller('ShowController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$location',
function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location) {

var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
list = $firebaseArray(ref);
console.log(list); // []
console.log(location.hash.split('#/')[1]); // -K9hr32rhror_
var key = location.hash.split('#/')[1];
console.log(list.$getRecord(key)); // null
console.log(list.$keyAt(0)); // null
console.log(list.$indexFor(key)); // -1
```

Next I tried using `ng-repeat="record in collection | filter : key">` but I can't figure out what `key` should be.

I also googled "Angular Firebase CRUD SHOW page" but none of the example CRUD apps had SHOW pages. Am I misunderstanding something fundamental? E.g., should I build the SHOW and EDIT views with `<ng-hide>` and `<ng-show>` on the INDEX page, and not bother to make separate SHOW and EDIT pages?

Comment: Glad to see my answer helped. If there are no other considerations, can you mark it as accepted. It's good to keep the unanswered queue clean.

Comment: The green checkmark is accepted? I tried the upvote but it says I don't have enough points to upvote.

Comment: You can upvote at 15. Which you just surpassed :)

Comment: To display a single record with Angular, should I use ng-repeat or is there another directive for single records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The problem you're dealing with is asynchronous data flow.**

```
app.controller('ShowController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$location',
function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
  var key = location.hash.split('#/')[1];
  $scope.list = $firebaseArray(ref); // data is downloading
  console.log($scope.list.length); // will be undefined, data is downloading
  $scope.list.$loaded().then(function(list) {
    console.log(list); // data has been downloaded!
    list.$getRecord(key); // data is available
  });
});
```

But `.$loaded()` is usually unnecessary because AngularFire knows when to trigger `$digest`. In your case you want to use a `$firebaseObject`.

```
app.controller('ShowController', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$location',
function($scope, $firebaseObject, $location) {
  var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/");
  var key = location.hash.split('#/')[1];
  var itemRef = ref.child(key);
  $scope.item = $firebaseObject(itemRef); 
});
```

This grabs the single item based off of the `key`, rather than downloading the entire list and plucking out one item.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, David East, the problem was asynchronous data. Here are two working controllers. The first controller gets the data array and selects the record I want out of the array:

```
app.controller('ShowController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', '$location',
function($scope, $firebaseArray, $location) {
  // set up Firebase
  var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/"); // goes to Firebase URL (fbURL)
  var list = $firebaseArray(ref); // puts
  list.$loaded().then(function(x) { // promise that executes when asynchronous data has loaded
    var key = location.hash.split('#/')[1]; // parses key from URL query string
    var showItem = list.$getRecord(key); // gets the record using the key passed in from the URL query string
    var showItems = []; // make an array
    showItems.push(showItem); // push the record into the array
    $scope.showItems = showItems; // attach the array to $scope
    // now 'ng-repeat="showIdea in showIdeas"' will iterate through the array, which has only one element
    // i.e., this is how you make Angular display one thing
  })
  .catch(function(error) { // if the data doesn't load
    console.log("Error:", error);
  });
}]);
```

The second controller uses David East's suggestion of using `$firebaseObject` to download only the record I want. I added some code to make it display using `ng-repeat`. Is there another way to display a single record with Angular?

```
app.controller('ShowController', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$location',
function($scope, $firebaseObject, $location) {
  // set up Firebase
  var ref = new Firebase("https://my-firebase.firebaseio.com/"); // goes to Firebase URL (fbURL)
  var key = location.hash.split('#/')[1]; // parses key from URL query string
  var itemRef = ref.child(key); // sets up the query
  var showItems = []; // make an array
  showItems.push($firebaseObject(itemRef)); // makes the query and push the record into the array
  $scope.showItems = showItems; // attach the array to $scope
}]);
```

And here's the view:

```
<table ng-repeat="showItem in showItems">
  <tr><td>Name:</td><td>{{showItem.itemName}}</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Title:</td><td>{{showItem.itemTitle}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular firebase crud in simple way and form
https://youtu.be/Ao4sdagqpvg